# Suppose $AB=BA$ and $A^{1965}=B^{2015}=I$. Prove that $A+B+I $ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, contest-math

Supppse $A $ abd $B $ are matrices, $AB=BA $ and $A^{1965}=B^{2015}=I $. Prove that $A+B+I $ is invertible.

I want to prove that $(A+B+I)C=I $ I have no idea how to start. Can any one give some hint?

Comment: From what contest is this?  Please provide details.

Comment: It is significant that $2015$ is not a multiple of $3$.

Comment: That is not what you want to prove; the quantifier on $C$ is important. Anyway, what equivalent conditions do you know for a matrix to be invertible? (I assume $A, B$ are matrices?)

Comment: Because $AB=BA$, general nonsense about joint eigenvectors means that it suffices to prove the proposition where $A, B, I$ are all $1\times 1$ matrices.

Comment: @Aaron: So the whole thing is only about saying "Let $x\cdot p(x)-a$ be the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt[1965]{1}+\sqrt[2015]{1}+1$, so x=$\frac{1}{a}p(x)$ is the inverse"?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I would phrase it as "If $a$ and $b$ are 1965th and 2015th roots of unity, show that $a+b\neq -1$.

Comment: @Bryan $A^{1965}=0$ would make $A$ nilpotent, but that isn't the condition int he problem.

Answer (score 5):

In case the hints in the comments were not enough, I have written up a complete solution.  Hover your mouse over to view it.  I wanted to break it up into multiple paragraphs, but I couldn't get the spoiler tags to work that way, so sorry if the formatting is a bit bad.

> Because there are no repeated roots in the equations of the form $x^n-1=0$, the minimal polynomials of $A$ and $B$ have no repeated roots, and hence $A$ and $B$ are both diagonalizable.  Since they commute, they are simultaneously diagonalizable, i.e., we can find a basis for our space of vectors that are both eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$.  Let $v$ be a common eigenvector of $A$ and $B$, so that $Av=av$ and $Bv=bv$.  We know that $a^{1965}=b^{2015}=1$.  Further, $v$ is an eigenvector of $A+B+I$ with eigenvalue $a+b+1$.  Since we have a basis of eigenvectors like this, showing that $A+B+I$ is invertible is equivalent to showing that $a+b+1\neq 0$.  Suppose that $a+b=-1$, where $a$ and $b$ lie on the unit circle in $\mathbb C$.  Since their imaginary parts cancel, $a$ and $b$ must be of the form $x+iy, z-iy$.  However, because there are at most $2$ points with a given $y$ coordinate on the unit circle, we must have that either $b=-a$ or $b=\overline{a}$.  In the first case, $a+b=0\neq -1$, and in the second case, $a,b=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{-3}}{2}$, which are both primitive third roots of unity.

Now, as @Omnomnomnom remarked, $2015$ is not a multiple of $3$.

Comment: In your solution, you show that $A$ and $B$ have a common vector $v$. How do we know such $v$ is also an eigenvector of $A+B+I$? Also, if $v$ is indeed an eigenvector of $A+B+I$, how do we know its eigenvalue is $a+b+1$? What it there exists some eigenvector of $A+B+I$ which is not a common eigenvector of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: $(A+B+I)v=Av+Bv+Iv=av+bv+v=(a+b+1)v$.  For your last question, we are using the fact that we have a basis of vectors that are common eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$, which therefore gives a basis of eigenvectors for $A+B+I$.

Comment: I see. I'm not quite understand the statement 'we can find a basis for our space of vectors that are both eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$', can you elaborate?

Comment: There exists a basis $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$ of $V$ such that each $v_i$ is both an eigenvector of $A$ and an eigenvector of $B$.